# datetime format in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime

I have the following **registerdate** table in my db.

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> registerdate { get; set; }
```

Because of my model is auto-generated and it says "Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application" i dont want to touch it.

So this is my controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search, DateTime? search2)
    {
        if (searchBy == "ID")
        {
            return View(db.students.Where(x => x.studentid == search).ToList());
        }
        else if (searchBy == "grade")
        {
            return View(db.students.Where(x => x.grades == search).ToList());
        }
        else if (searchBy == "registerdate")
        {
            return View(db.students.Where(x => x.registerdate == search2).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            return View(db.students.Where(x => x.studentname.Contains(search)).ToList());
        }
    }
```

and i use following code in my view:

```
        <p>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
            <b>Search by:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchby", "ID", true) <text>StudentID</text>
            @Html.RadioButton("searchby", "grade") <text>Grade</text>
            @Html.RadioButton("searchby", "registerdate") <text>RegisterDate</text>
            <br /><br />
            @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        }
        </p>
```

and to display:

```
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.registerdate)
```

So basically i can perform search by id, grade or studentname. But it doesnt work for registerdate. When i search by registerdate, it brings no results.

Any idea why i am not getting any results if i search by registerdate?

Comment: Could you run the code and inspect whats in search2 when it hits the first line.

Comment: Have you checked the format in the database? Is it the same with the search? I could suggest you also to use `.Contains()` extension method

Comment: Is the `DateTime` string format that is sent in from the client side being correctly bound to the `DateTime` property on the model?

Comment: Barry, I updated my question, adding the search section. Seems like i am missing search2 but where to add it?

Comment: lnanikian, yes it seems same format.

Comment: Russ Cam, i am not sure, how to check it?

Comment: Try casting datetime:
`(DateTime)x.registerdate == (DateTime)search2`

Comment: @ŞenolŞahin, To check it, add a breakpoint and start with debugging. Did you add a breakpoing at `if (searchBy == "ID")` and check whether the parameter `search2` is null or contains a value?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the `DateTime` comparison issue.  I am assuming when creating / registering a student, you are setting `RegiseterDate` to something like `DateTime.Now`

```
student.RegisterDate = DateTime.Now();
```

As a result, the register date is stored as `4/20/2014 09:38:27`.  Now, when you send a date from the web interface (using a date picker or something similar), your `search2` variable is set to `4/20/2014 00:00:00`.  You can clearly see that the first April 20th DateTime is not equal to the second April 20th DateTime.

Typically, you could compare DateTime variables where you only care about the date portion using `student.RegisterDate.Date == search2`, but EF cannot convert that .Date() to SQL.  So, the easiest way is to compare the entire range of the day using something like below:

```
    //search2 == 4/20/2014 00:00:00
    var endDate = search2.Value.AddDays(1);
    //endDate == 4/21/2014 00:00:00
    return View(db.students.Where(x => x.registerdate >= search2 
&& x.registerdate < endDate).ToList());
    //return all students where registerdate is between 4/20/2014 00:00:00 and 4/21/2014 00:00:00.
```

Comment: Hi Tommy, i am trying your code but it doesnt allow me to type in AddDays. Doesnt contain a definition for it.

Comment: @ŞenolŞahin  Ah, forgot that it was a nullable parameter.  You have to addDays() to the value of the object.